# Running SikuliX Script on VPS while computer off?

Tags: vps, sikuli

I'm trying to run a SikuliX Script 24/7 on a VPS but I do not want to leave my computer on all the time while it runs. I know sikuli requires that you have a monitor, so I am not sure how I can have it run while my VPS isn't even open on my computer.

Answer (score 1):

If your VPS is running Linux you could use a tool such as [Xpra](https://www.xpra.org/), it allows for an X application to be run even when the client disconnects. It can also be used with a nested X server like Xephyr to run a full remote desktop that persists disconnects.

On Windows Server this [this superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/558920/disable-windows-server-2012-automatic-log-off) page details how to allow a Windows Server RDP session to persist even after the client has disconnected.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately I'm running Windows Server2012/8.1

Comment: Added a link for for Windows Server though I am unsure if it is exactly what you were looking for.

Comment: I will investigate this. Thank you for your time!